# How to print numbered lines from one .txt to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

i am trying to print lines of text from one .txt file to another .txt but with each line numbered in the second file.

For example if the first 1.txt file is:

```
Chocolate
Vanilla
Strawberry
```

---

Than the second 2.txt file should be:

```
[0] Chocolate
[1] Vanilla
[2] Strawberry
```

---

I am trying to use Python 3 code to do this, please help. Thanks

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: fh_in = open(input('Enter input file name: '), 'r')
fh_out = open(input('Enter output file name: '), 'w')
for i, line in fh_in.items():
        fh_out.write('{} = {}'.format(i + 1, line.strip()))                                               fh_in.close()
fh_out.close()

Comment: It's hard to read your code in a comment because it doesn't keep the formatting. Please [edit] your code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
file1 = open('1.txt', 'r') 
file2 = open('2.txt', 'w')

for idx,line in enumerate(file1):
    file2.write('['+str(idx)+'] '+line)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: Thank you , it is working but seems to only print the first line

Comment: Hi Rob! I just tested my script under Python 3.5 and was able to create file 2.txt without problem. Could there be an issue with your input file 1.txt?